# Unable to run FlappyBird PLE in google colab

Tags: pygame, google-colaboratory, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to use FlappyBird environment in Google Colab for reinforcement learning task. I have downloaded the PLE and PYGAME and set the video driver as 'dummy'. Though the import is successful, it throws 'couldn't find png' error when I instantiate the FlappyBird() class.

I have installed the PLE and PyGame.

```
import os
!git clone https://github.com/ntasfi/PyGame-Learning-Environment.git
os.chdir('PyGame-Learning-Environment')
!pip install -e .
!pip install pygame
os.chdir('/content')
```

Set videoDriver as 'dummy' because no video device is available in colab.

```
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER']='dummy'
```

Imported ple and flappyBird

```
from ple.games.flappybird import FlappyBird
from ple import PLE  
game = FlappyBird()
```

It throws an error:

```
error:  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-c0174ea47a10> in <module>()
  3 
  4 
----> 5 game = FlappyBird()
  6 p = PLE(game, fps=30, display_screen=True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ple/games/flappybird/__init__.py in __init__(self, width, height, pipe_gap)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ple/games/flappybird/__init__.py in _load_images(self)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ple/games/flappybird/__init__.py in <listcomp>(.0)

error: Couldn't open /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ple/games/flappybird/assets/redbird-upflap.png
```

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the install, and it looks like `pip` does not install the file `redbird-upflap.png`.  Or at least after installing as per the OP's instructions, no file existed on my machine with that name, except the one in the `git` download.

Perhaps you can install the file manually (perhaps NOT in google colab).

```
sudo cp PyGame-Learning-Environment/ple/games/flappybird/assets/redbird-upflap.png /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ple/games/flappybird/assets/redbird-upflap.png
```

But there could be a bunch more files that don't get installed properly too.  Is it possible to use this software without the `pip install .` ?

Comment: I wanted to run this in colab. But the problem was all the files were not getting installed which was causing problems. So I locally installed all the files from git directory in my drive .Then imported PLE from there and everything worked fine. Thank you. :)